# Como saber qual é a ferramenta de SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, linux, windows

Eu estou no Visual Studio 2017 que está com conexão com o banco de dados SQL server ,o SQL server está rodando no servidor Linux, esse servidor está rodando na nuvem.

O que estou tentando fazer é copiar o banco de dado direto na base de dados SQL server que está rodando no servidor Linux.

OBS: meu Visual Studio está instalado no windows no meu computador local.

O que acontece é que banco vou copiar o backup do bando de dados direto no servidor SQL server ele gera esse erro abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tudo que preciso é saber qual a ferramenta que devo no servidor Linux para conseguir copiar o backup para a base de dados SQL Server.

Comment: Verifique se o seguinte documento atende ao que necessita: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-restore-database

Comment: Eu seguir as orientações descritas nessa URL, mas ao tentar efetuar a operação me deparei com o mesmo problema.

Comment: No texto de sua pergunta, poderia detalhar o que significa "esse servidor está rodando na nuvem"?   Em suma, qual serviço está utilizando. Por exemplo, no caso do Azure existe diferença entre "Azure SQL Database" e "SQL Server no Azure MV".

Comment: É um servidor Linux rodando no SQL serve.